# regular expression to specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

My string have a two part and separated by `/`

I want **left side** string of slash accept any string except `"HAHAHA"` **end of word**
And **right side** string of slash accept any string and allow use `"HAHAHA"` in end of string

**only** by `Regular Expression` and `match` function to return result parts

**For example:**

**Accept** :  `fooo/baarHAHAHA`

**Reject** : `fooHAHAHA/baaar`

I want if string have one part, for example `baarHAHAHA`, accept but result like this:

**string:** `baarHAHAHA`

**Group1:** `empty`

**Group2:** `baarHAHAHA`

Have any idea?

Comment: Do any of the below answers help?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes. Thank you, lazy quantifier solved my problem

Comment: @mandy8055 I want use regex for any route pattern

Comment: No, For example : nutella.html reject and chocolate/nutella.html accept when part1(required)/part2(optional)

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/3HBvwU/9) help?

Comment: Thank you, your regex not flexible for my target

Comment: Please, don't modify completly the question. Ask a new one instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
^(\w*?)(?<!HAHAHA)\/?(\w+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`(\w*?)`** - Represents first capturing group capturing the word characters(`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) zero or more times **lazily**.
- **`(?<!HAHAHA)`** - Represents a negative look-behind not matching if the first captured group contains `HAHAHA` at the end.
- **`\/?`** - Matches `/` literally zero or one time.
- **`(\w+)`** - Represents second capturing group matching word characters(`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`) one or more times.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/3HBvwU/6)

```js
const regex = /^(\w*?)(?<!HAHAHA)\/?(\w+)$/gm;
const str = `
fooo/baarHAHAHA
fooHAHAHA/baaar
/baar
barHAHAHA
`;
let m;
let resultString = "";
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    if(m[1] === "")resultString = resultString.concat(`GROUP 1: empty\nGROUP 2: ${m[2]}\n`);
    else resultString = resultString.concat(`GROUP 1: ${m[1]}\nGROUP 2: ${m[2]}\n`);
}

console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Thank you, lazy quantifier solved my problem. But by this `regex` for pattern (part1/part2) part1 always is optional

Comment: It is true. But what if the first part is needed? this is new question

Comment: for example : baarHAHAHA reject and foo/baarHAHAHA accept ?

Comment: Yes, can you answer it?

Comment: Update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `regex` for this, which is good since it is quite slow. A simple `string.split()` should be enough to separate the parts. Then you can just check if the word contains "HAHAHA" with the `string.endsWith()` method.

```js
const a = 'fooHAHAHA/bar';
const b = 'foo/bar';
const c = 'fooHAHAHA';

console.log(a.split('/')); // Array [ 'fooHAHAHA', 'bar' ]
console.log(b.split('/')); // Array [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
console.log(c.split('/')); // Array [ 'fooHAHAHA' ]

// therefore ...
function splitMyString(str) {
    const strSplit = str.split('/');
    if (strSplit.length > 1) {
       if (strSplit[0].endsWith('HAHAHA')) {
           return ''; // or whatever you want to do if it gets rejected ...
       }
    }
    return str;
}

console.log('a: ', splitMyString(a)); // ''
console.log('b: ', splitMyString(b)); // foo/bar
console.log('c: ', splitMyString(c)); // fooHAHAHA
```

Alternative non-regex solution:

```js
const a = 'fooHAHAHA/bar';
const b = 'foo/bar';
const c = 'fooHAHAHA';

function splitMyString(str) {
    const separator = str.indexOf('/');
    if (separator !== -1) {
      const firstPart = str.substring(0, separator);
      if (firstPart.endsWith('HAHAHA')) {
         return ''; // or whatever you want to do if it gets rejected ...
      }
    }
    return str;
}

console.log('a: ', splitMyString(a)); // ''
console.log('b: ', splitMyString(b)); // foo/bar
console.log('c: ', splitMyString(c)); // fooHAHAHA
```

Comment: I think it was some sort of exercise, soprobably regex was needed

Answer (score 0):

```
var str, re;

function match(rgx, str) {
  this.str = str;
  this.patt = rgx
  var R = [], r;
  while (r = re.exec(str)) {
    R.push({
      "match": r[0],
      "groups": r.slice(1)
    })
  }
  return R;
}

str = `
fooo/baarHAHAHA
fooHAHAHA/baaar
/baar
barHAHAHA
barr/bhHAHAHA
`;

re = /(?<=\s|^)(.*?)\/(.*?HAHAHA)(?=\s)/g;

console.log(match(re, str))
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Edit: When I make this code I think to letting user to call the str and when call it, it will return the mactheds and groups. But, if I make like `this.str = str` and have `return` too, `this.str` will be declined.